# Sleep doesn't wait

Tags: php

My script to check if HTTP servers are responding... it supposed to ask all servers from the list every 60 seconds. But it doesn't wait at all. Any idea why? It does execute sleep line (as when I do some echo there, it does appear), but doesn't stop for those 60 seconds... only stops when child limit is reached (that is in this case - never). Any idea why?

PHP **5.4.41-0+deb7u1**

```
<?php

    echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] Starting...\n";

    declare(ticks = 1); // cpu directive

    error_reporting(0); // screw warnings
    set_time_limit(0); // no limits!

    $ctx = stream_context_create(array( // timeout file_get_contents context
        'http' => array(
            'timeout' => 30 // half of time between requests
            )
        )
    );

    $test_urls = array( // test urls
        'URL1' => 'http://www.google.com',
        'URL2' => 'http://www.ebay.de'
    );

    $max=10;
    $child=0;
    $rec_id=0;

    function sig_handler($signo) {
        global $child;
        switch ($signo) {
                case SIGCHLD:
                $child -= 1;
        }
    }

    pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, "sig_handler"); // register fork signal handler to count running children

    $loop = 0;

    while (true){ // <main_loop>
    $loop++;

        foreach($test_urls as $uid => $url){ // <test_urls>

        echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] ENTERING LOOP:$loop\n";

            while ($child >= $max) {
                        sleep(1);
                    }

            $child++;
            $rec_id++;

            if($rec_id > 999999) $rec_id = 1; // limit rec_id, so it wouldn't cause an out of bounds error

            $pid=pcntl_fork();

            if($pid){

                // If you're here, something is totally messed up.

            }else{ // <fork>

                $req_start = microtime(true);
                $result = file_get_contents($url,NULL,$ctx);                
                $req_time = microtime(true) - $req_start;

                if($result) echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] OK - $req_time\n";
                else echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] ERROR - $req_time\n";

                sleep(1); // avoid segmentation fault, when fork ends before handling signals
                exit;

            } // </fork>

        } // </test_urls>

    echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: $loop\n";
        sleep(60); // test every 60 seconds (if childs are available!)
    echo "[".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."] WAKING UP LOOP: $loop\n";

    } // </main_loop>

    while($child != 0){
        sleep(1);
    }
?>
```

**RESULTS:***

```
[2015-08-05 18:17:43] Starting...
[2015-08-05 18:17:43] ENTERING LOOP:1
[2015-08-05 18:17:43] ENTERING LOOP:1
[2015-08-05 18:17:43] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 1
[2015-08-05 18:17:43] OK - 0.36189103126526
[2015-08-05 18:17:44] OK - 0.99003601074219
[2015-08-05 18:17:44] WAKING UP LOOP: 1
[2015-08-05 18:17:44] ENTERING LOOP:2
[2015-08-05 18:17:44] ENTERING LOOP:2
[2015-08-05 18:17:44] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 2
[2015-08-05 18:17:44] OK - 0.30263018608093
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] WAKING UP LOOP: 2
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] ENTERING LOOP:3
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] ENTERING LOOP:3
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 3
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] OK - 0.445955991745
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] OK - 1.2020018100739
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] WAKING UP LOOP: 3
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] ENTERING LOOP:4
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] ENTERING LOOP:4
[2015-08-05 18:17:45] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 4
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] OK - 1.0700960159302
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] OK - 0.5119640827179
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] WAKING UP LOOP: 4
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] ENTERING LOOP:5
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] ENTERING LOOP:5
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 5
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] WAKING UP LOOP: 5
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] ENTERING LOOP:6
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] ENTERING LOOP:6
[2015-08-05 18:17:46] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 6
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] OK - 0.43205118179321
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] WAKING UP LOOP: 6
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] ENTERING LOOP:7
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] ENTERING LOOP:7
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] OK - 1.3988509178162
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 7
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] OK - 0.59426283836365
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] WAKING UP LOOP: 7
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] ENTERING LOOP:8
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] ENTERING LOOP:8
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] GOING TO SLEEP ON LOOP: 8
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] OK - 1.2100639343262
[2015-08-05 18:17:47] OK - 0.5920991897583
```

Comment: Wouldn't `exit;` kill the script execution all together so it would never reach a second iteration...?

Comment: Nope, exit exits fork. It does execute the loop forever, but without waiting... when I give "echo 'something';" directly after and before sleep(60), it does echo that every time. Not exiting forks causes segmentation faults.

Comment: @FlashThunder im 90% certain it will exit the `foreach` .. if not th parenting (and questionable) `while(true)` try `continue`

Comment: Edited to prove that you are wrong. Please check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sleep` can be interrupted by signals, in which case it will return the remaining seconds and doesn't continue. One of the signal it might receive is when the child is killed during execution (`SIGCHLD`). You can check the return value of `sleep` to determine whether there was a signal that interrupted it, or not, but I guess it does exit on the `SIGCHLD`.

On linux machines the return value [will be the remaining seconds to sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php), so you could put the sleep in a loop and sleep until the remaining seconds is 0, or if there was an other type of error (which is signalled by a `FALSE` response)

something like this might work:

```
$timeLeft = 60;
while ($timeLeft > 0) {
   $timeLeft = sleep($timeLeft);
}
```

Also please note, in your original code you have a comment stating:

```
// If you're here, something is totally f***ed up.   *<-- Edited for family friendliness*
```

which is actually the parent part after the fork has been completed, so that branch will actually execute every time. You might want to change this comment, as it might be confusing for you or any other person reading the code, or just remove it completely by having an `if (!$pid) {` check instead

Comment: That has sense... any way to avoid that?

Comment: That worked, even not missing seconds... cool, thanx... Not counting, it's not a PHP syntax, but it's ok. Thank you.

Comment: This makes sense.. Never would have guessed it.. But doesn't it defeat the purpose of `sleep` really ?

Comment: @Pogrindis: actually `sleep` works like this in many other programming languages as well, [including C](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), from which probably all other implementations are copied. For example in Java the sleep [will throw exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) that you need to handle in case it received a signal (so it's more apparent that it might not sleep the whole time)

Comment: I totally didn't suspect that it may break sleeps on `sigchld`. At least it breaks it after full second in PHP, thats why the answer works correctly.